# SQL Gaps/Islands Question - Determine if someone has worked for X years without a Y days break

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression, gaps-and-islands

Working on problem for a company in Japan. The government has some rules such as... If you are on a work visa:

1. You cannot work for more than 3 years at a **company** without taking 30 days off
2. You cannot work for the same staffing company for more than 5 years without taking 6 months off

So we want to figure out if anyone will be violating either rule in the next 30/60/90 days.

Sample data (list of contracts):

```
if object_id('tempdb..#sampleDates') is not null drop table #sampleDates
create table #sampleDates (UserId int, CompanyID int, WorkPeriodStart datetime, WorkPeriodEnd datetime)
insert #sampleDates (UserId, CompanyID, WorkPeriodStart, WorkPeriodEnd) values (27809, 972, '2019-10-10', '2020-10-10')
insert #sampleDates (UserId, CompanyID, WorkPeriodStart, WorkPeriodEnd) values (27853, 484, '2019-10-10', '2020-10-10')
insert #sampleDates (UserId, CompanyID, WorkPeriodStart, WorkPeriodEnd) values (27856, 172, '2019-10-10', '2020-10-10')
insert #sampleDates (UserId, CompanyID, WorkPeriodStart, WorkPeriodEnd) values (27857, 1234, '2015-01-01', '2015-12-31')
insert #sampleDates (UserId, CompanyID, WorkPeriodStart, WorkPeriodEnd) values (27857, 1234, '2016-01-01', '2017-02-28')
insert #sampleDates (UserId, CompanyID, WorkPeriodStart, WorkPeriodEnd) values (27857, 1234, '2017-01-01', '2017-12-31')
insert #sampleDates (UserId, CompanyID, WorkPeriodStart, WorkPeriodEnd) values (27857, 1234, '2018-01-01', '2018-12-31')
insert #sampleDates (UserId, CompanyID, WorkPeriodStart, WorkPeriodEnd) values (27857, 1234, '2019-01-01', '2020-01-31')
insert #sampleDates (UserId, CompanyID, WorkPeriodStart, WorkPeriodEnd) values (27857, 1234, '2020-01-01', '2020-12-31')
insert #sampleDates (UserId, CompanyID, WorkPeriodStart, WorkPeriodEnd) values (27897, 179, '2019-10-10', '2020-10-10')
```

My first issue is possibly overlapping dates. I am close to a solution on that already, but until I know how to solve the Working X years/ Y Days off issue, I'm not sure what the output of my cte or temp table should look like.

I don't expect anyone to do the work for me, but I want to find an article that can tell me:

- How can I determine if someone has taken any breaks in the time period, and for how long (gaps between date ranges)?
- How can I figure if they will have worked for 3/5 years without a 30/180 days break in the next 30/60/90 days?

This seemed so simple until I started coding the procedure.

Thanks for any help in advance.

**EDIT:**

For what it's worth, here's my second working attempt at eliminating overlapping dates (first version used a dense_rank approach and it worked until I screwed something up, went with something simple):

```
;with CJ as (
    select UserId, CompanyID, WorkPeriodStart, WorkPeriodEnd from #sampleDates c 
)
select 
       c.CompanyID,
       c.WorkPeriodStart,
       min(t1.WorkPeriodEnd) as EndDate
from CJ c
inner join CJ t1 on c.WorkPeriodStart <= t1.WorkPeriodEnd and c.UserId = t1.UserId and c.CompanyID = t1.CompanyID
    and not exists(select * from CJ t2 where t1.UserId = t2.UserId and t1.CompanyID = t2.CompanyID and t1.WorkPeriodEnd >= t2.WorkPeriodStart AND t1.WorkPeriodEnd < t2.WorkPeriodEnd) 
where not exists(select * from CJ c2 where c.UserId = c2.UserId and c.CompanyID = c2.CompanyID and c.WorkPeriodStart > c2.WorkPeriodStart AND c.WorkPeriodStart <= c2.WorkPeriodEnd) 

group by c.UserId, c.CompanyID, c.WorkPeriodStart 
order by c.UserId, c.WorkPeriodStart
```

Comment: Busy right now, but can write your query in a couple of hours if no one else does.

Comment: A query would be great, but an article would be great too. Haha

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer: This is an incomplete answer.**

I can continue later, but this shows how to compute the islands. Then identifying the offender ones shouldn't be that complicated.

See augmented example. I added user `27897` that has three islands: 0, 1, and 2. See below:

```
create table t (UserId int, CompanyID int, WorkPeriodStart date, WorkPeriodEnd date);

insert t (UserId, CompanyID, WorkPeriodStart, WorkPeriodEnd) values
  (27809, 972, '2019-10-10', '2020-10-10'),
  (27853, 484, '2019-10-10', '2020-10-10'),
  (27856, 172, '2019-10-10', '2020-10-10'),
  (27857, 1234, '2015-01-01', '2015-12-31'),
  (27857, 1234, '2016-01-01', '2017-02-28'),
  (27857, 1234, '2017-01-01', '2017-12-31'),
  (27857, 1234, '2018-01-01', '2018-12-31'),
  (27857, 1234, '2019-01-01', '2020-01-31'),
  (27857, 1234, '2020-01-01', '2020-12-31'),
  (27897, 179, '2015-05-28', '2015-09-30'),
  (27897, 179, '2017-03-11', '2017-04-30'),
  (27897, 188, '2017-02-20', '2017-07-07'),
  (27897, 179, '2019-10-10', '2020-10-10');
```

With this data, the query that computes the island for each row can look like:

```
select *,
  sum(hop) over(partition by UserId order by WorkPeriodStart) as island
from (
  select *,
    case when WorkPeriodStart > dateadd(day, 1, max(WorkPeriodEnd) 
      over(partition by UserId 
           order by WorkPeriodStart 
           rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding))
         then 1 else 0 end as hop
  from t
) x
order by UserId, WorkPeriodStart
```

Result:

```
UserId  CompanyID  WorkPeriodStart  WorkPeriodEnd  hop  island
------  ---------  ---------------  -------------  ---  ------
 27809        972  2019-10-10       2020-10-10       0       0
 27853        484  2019-10-10       2020-10-10       0       0
 27856        172  2019-10-10       2020-10-10       0       0
 27857       1234  2015-01-01       2015-12-31       0       0
 27857       1234  2016-01-01       2017-02-28       0       0
 27857       1234  2017-01-01       2017-12-31       0       0
 27857       1234  2018-01-01       2018-12-31       0       0
 27857       1234  2019-01-01       2020-01-31       0       0
 27857       1234  2020-01-01       2020-12-31       0       0
 27897        179  2015-05-28       2015-09-30       0       0
 27897        188  2017-02-20       2017-07-07       1       1
 27897        179  2017-03-11       2017-04-30       0       1
 27897        179  2019-10-10       2020-10-10       1       2
```

Now, we can augment this query to get the "worked days" for each island, and the "days off" before each island, by doing:

```
select *,
  datediff(day, s, e) + 1 as worked,
  datediff(day, lag(e) over(partition by UserId order by island), s) as prev_days_off
from (
  select UserId, island, min(WorkPeriodStart) as s, max(WorkPeriodEnd) as e
  from (
    select *,
      sum(hop) over(partition by UserId order by WorkPeriodStart) as island
    from (
      select *,
        case when WorkPeriodStart > dateadd(day, 1, max(WorkPeriodEnd) 
          over(partition by UserId 
               order by WorkPeriodStart 
               rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding))
             then 1 else 0 end as hop
      from t
    ) x
  ) y
  group by UserId, island
) x
order by UserId, island
```

Result:

```
UserId  island  s           e           worked  prev_days_off
------  ------  ----------  ----------  ------  -------------
 27809       0  2019-10-10  2020-10-10     367         <null>
 27853       0  2019-10-10  2020-10-10     367         <null>
 27856       0  2019-10-10  2020-10-10     367         <null>
 27857       0  2015-01-01  2020-12-31    2192         <null>
 27897       0  2015-05-28  2015-09-30     126         <null>
 27897       1  2017-02-20  2017-07-07     138            509
 27897       2  2019-10-10  2020-10-10     367            825
```

This result is much close to what you need. That data is actually useful to filter rows according to your criteria.

Comment: This actually comes closer to what I am looking for. Your code for removing overlapping dates suffers from the same flaw that my code does (in my edit) .
If you look at the dates for user 27857 there should be a continuous date range from 2016-01-01 to 2017-12-31. (Unless the worked/day_off calcs already take that into account)
This was not part of my original question anyway, so I will move on to the days on/off calcs, understand what you sql is doing and get back to you. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Also, does you real name happen to be Vlad?

Comment: I understand your tsql logic now. Helps a great deal. Now I need to:

1) Make sure that all date overlaps are handled correctly. 2) Handle the two laws differently because the 3 year law relies on the User working at the same companyid for 3 years, so I need to group by company in the inner query.  3) write an outer query to grab the last island only

Comment: @PaulPerrick Yep, that's my name. I'm quite busy these days; if I have time, I'll circle back to see if I can write a whole solution.

Comment: @VladTheImpaler  I appreciate it. I think I am back on the right track now.

Comment: Thank again for your help. I found a number of issues with the tsql (one being that I remembered they are using SQL 2008 server still and the lag function is not available, need to self reference the table). Also, I had to circle back as well, my anniversary was Sunday and I almost forgot it = (

Comment: @PaulPerrick SQL Server 2008 is quite old at this point. I think it reached end of life already.

Comment: Yes it has! I have commented about it more than a few times with my client but to no avail (yet).

Answer (score 1):

This script merges any overlapping work periods and then calculates the total days worked within the previous 3 and 5 year periods.  Then takes this value and determines if this is more than the maximum working days allowed within that period by `UserId` and `CompanyId` for the 3 year limit, and just by `UserId` for the 5 year limit.  (Is this a correct interpretation of the rules in your question?)

From this it then simply adds on `30`, `60` and `90` days to that total, to see if that larger value would be over the respective limits.  Given the different grouping rules, this would be cleaner as 2 queries (no duplication of `UserId` for 5 year rule) but the result is still a flag against any offending `UserId`.

In the example below you can see `UserId = 27857` only violating the 5 year rule at present, but then also violating the 3 year rule should they stay on for another `60` days.  In addition, `UserId = 27858` is currently okay, but will violate the 5 year rule in `60` days.

I have made some assumptions about how you define a year and whether or not your `WorkPeriodEnd` values are inclusive or not, so do check that your required logic is properly applied.

### Script

```
if object_id('tempdb..#sampleDates') is not null drop table #sampleDates
create table #sampleDates (UserId int, CompanyId int, WorkPeriodStart datetime, WorkPeriodEnd datetime)
insert #sampleDates values
 (27809, 972, '2019-10-10', '2020-10-10')
,(27853, 484, '2019-10-10', '2020-10-10')
,(27856, 172, '2019-10-10', '2020-10-10')

,(27857, 1234, '2015-01-01', '2015-12-31')
,(27857, 1234, '2016-01-01', '2017-02-28')
,(27857, 1234, '2017-01-01', '2017-12-31')
,(27857, 1234, '2018-01-01', '2018-12-31')
,(27857, 1234, '2019-01-01', '2020-01-31')
,(27857, 1234, '2020-01-01', '2020-05-31')

,(27858, 1234, '2015-01-01', '2015-12-31')
,(27858, 1234, '2016-01-01', '2017-02-28')
,(27858, 1234, '2017-01-01', '2017-12-31')
,(27858, 1234, '2018-01-01', '2018-12-31')
,(27858, 1234, '2019-09-01', '2020-01-31')
,(27858, 1234, '2020-01-01', '2020-08-31')

,(27859, 12345, '2015-01-01', '2015-12-31')
,(27859, 12346, '2016-01-01', '2017-02-28')
,(27859, 12347, '2017-01-01', '2017-12-31')
,(27859, 12348, '2018-01-01', '2018-12-31')
,(27859, 12349, '2019-01-01', '2020-01-31')
,(27859, 12340, '2020-01-01', '2020-12-31')

,(27897, 179, '2019-10-10', '2020-10-10')
;

declare @3YearsAgo date = dateadd(year,-3,getdate());
declare @3YearWorkingDays int = (365*3)-30;

declare @5YearsAgo date = dateadd(year,-5,getdate());
declare @5YearWorkingDays int = (365*5)-(365/2);

with p as
(
    select UserId
          ,CompanyId
          ,min(WorkPeriodStart) as WorkPeriodStart
          ,max(WorkPeriodEnd) as WorkPeriodEnd
    from(select l.*,
                sum(case when dateadd(day,1,l.PrevEnd) < l.WorkPeriodStart then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by l.UserId, l.CompanyId order by l.WorkPeriodStart rows unbounded preceding) as grp
        from(select d.*,
                    lag(d.WorkPeriodEnd) over (partition by d.UserId, d.CompanyId order by d.WorkPeriodEnd) as PrevEnd
            from #sampleDates as d
            ) as l
        ) as g
    group by grp
            ,UserId
            ,CompanyId
)
,d as
(
    select UserId
          ,CompanyId
          ,sum(case when @3YearsAgo < WorkPeriodEnd
                    then datediff(day
                                 ,case when @3YearsAgo between WorkPeriodStart and WorkPeriodEnd then @3YearsAgo else WorkPeriodStart end
                                 ,WorkPeriodEnd
                                 )
                    else 0
                    end
              ) as WorkingDays3YearsToToday
          
          ,sum(case when @5YearsAgo < WorkPeriodEnd
                    then datediff(day
                                 ,case when @5YearsAgo between WorkPeriodStart and WorkPeriodEnd then @5YearsAgo else WorkPeriodStart end
                                 ,WorkPeriodEnd
                                 )
                    else 0
                    end
               ) as WorkingDays5YearsToToday
    from p
    group by UserId
            ,CompanyId
)
select UserId
     ,CompanyId
     ,@3YearWorkingDays as Limit3Year
     ,@5YearWorkingDays as Limit5Year
     ,WorkingDays3YearsToToday
     ,WorkingDays5YearsToToday

     ,case when WorkingDays3YearsToToday > @3YearWorkingDays then 1 else 0 end as Violation3YearNow
     ,case when sum(WorkingDays5YearsToToday) over (partition by UserId) > @5YearWorkingDays then 1 else 0 end as Violation5YearNow
     
     ,case when WorkingDays3YearsToToday + 30 > @3YearWorkingDays then 1 else 0 end as Violation3Year30Day
     ,case when sum(WorkingDays5YearsToToday) over (partition by UserId) + 30 > @5YearWorkingDays then 1 else 0 end as Violation5Year30Day

     ,case when WorkingDays3YearsToToday + 60 > @3YearWorkingDays then 1 else 0 end as Violation3Year60Day
     ,case when sum(WorkingDays5YearsToToday) over (partition by UserId) + 60 > @5YearWorkingDays then 1 else 0 end as Violation5Year60Day

     ,case when WorkingDays3YearsToToday + 90 > @3YearWorkingDays then 1 else 0 end as Violation3Year90Day
     ,case when sum(WorkingDays5YearsToToday) over (partition by UserId) + 90 > @5YearWorkingDays then 1 else 0 end as Violation5Year90Day
from d
order by UserId
        ,CompanyId;
```

### Output

```
+--------+-----------+------------+------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+-------------------+-------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| UserId | CompanyId | Limit3Year | Limit5Year | WorkingDays3YearsToToday | WorkingDays5YearsToToday | Violation3YearNow | Violation5YearNow | Violation3Year30Day | Violation5Year30Day | Violation3Year60Day | Violation5Year60Day | Violation3Year90Day | Violation5Year90Day |
+--------+-----------+------------+------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+-------------------+-------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  27809 |       972 |       1065 |       1643 |                      366 |                      366 |                 0 |                 0 |                   0 |                   0 |                   0 |                   0 |                   0 |                   0 |
|  27853 |       484 |       1065 |       1643 |                      366 |                      366 |                 0 |                 0 |                   0 |                   0 |                   0 |                   0 |                   0 |                   0 |
|  27856 |       172 |       1065 |       1643 |                      366 |                      366 |                 0 |                 0 |                   0 |                   0 |                   0 |                   0 |                   0 |                   0 |
|  27857 |      1234 |       1065 |       1643 |                     1029 |                     1760 |                 0 |                 1 |                   0 |                   1 |                   1 |                   1 |                   1 |                   1 |
|  27858 |      1234 |       1065 |       1643 |                      877 |                     1608 |                 0 |                 0 |                   0 |                   0 |                   0 |                   1 |                   0 |                   1 |
|  27859 |     12340 |       1065 |       1643 |                      365 |                      365 |                 0 |                 1 |                   0 |                   1 |                   0 |                   1 |                   0 |                   1 |
|  27859 |     12345 |       1065 |       1643 |                        0 |                      147 |                 0 |                 1 |                   0 |                   1 |                   0 |                   1 |                   0 |                   1 |
|  27859 |     12346 |       1065 |       1643 |                        0 |                      424 |                 0 |                 1 |                   0 |                   1 |                   0 |                   1 |                   0 |                   1 |
|  27859 |     12347 |       1065 |       1643 |                      147 |                      364 |                 0 |                 1 |                   0 |                   1 |                   0 |                   1 |                   0 |                   1 |
|  27859 |     12348 |       1065 |       1643 |                      364 |                      364 |                 0 |                 1 |                   0 |                   1 |                   0 |                   1 |                   0 |                   1 |
|  27859 |     12349 |       1065 |       1643 |                      395 |                      395 |                 0 |                 1 |                   0 |                   1 |                   0 |                   1 |                   0 |                   1 |
|  27897 |       179 |       1065 |       1643 |                      366 |                      366 |                 0 |                 0 |                   0 |                   0 |                   0 |                   0 |                   0 |                   0 |
+--------+-----------+------------+------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+-------------------+-------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! This actually helps quite a bit to put me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I ended up with.

**<UselessExplanation>**

The issues I kept facing were:

- How can I handle any and all date range overlaps and determine just the days within the contract date ranges.
- The client is **STILL** using SQL 2008, so I need some old(er) school tsql.
- Ensure that the break times (times between contracts) is accurately calculated.

So I chose to come up with my own solution which is probably dumb, being that it needs to generate a record in memory for every Workday/Candidate combination. I do not see the contracts table going beyond the 5-10k record range. Only reason I'm going this direction.

I created a calendar table with every date in it from 1/1/1980 - 12/31/2050
I then left joined the contract ranges against the calendar table by CandidateId. These will be the dates worked.
Any dates in the calendar table that do not match a date within a contract range is a Break Day.

**</UselessExplanation>**

**Calendar table**

```
if object_id('CalendarTable') is not null drop table CalendarTable
go

create table CalendarTable (pk int identity, CalendarDate date )

declare @StartDate date = cast('1980-01-01' as date)
declare @EndDate date = cast('2050-12-31' as date)
while @StartDate <= @EndDate
begin
    insert into CalendarTable ( CalendarDate ) values ( @StartDate )
    set @StartDate = dateadd(dd, 1, @StartDate)
end
go
```

**Query for 5 year violations (working 5 years without a 6 month cool off period)**

```
declare @enddate date = dateadd(dd, 30, getdate()) 
declare @beginDate date = dateadd(dd, -180, dateadd(year, -5, getdate()))

select poss.CandidateId, 
min(work.CalendarDate) as FirstWorkDate, 
count(work.CandidateId) as workedDays, 
sum(case when work.CandidateId is null then 1 else 0 end) as breakDays, 
case when count(work.CandidateId) > (365*5) and sum(case when work.CandidateId is null then 1 else 0 end) < (365/2) then 1 else 0 end as Year5Violation,
case when count(work.CandidateId) > (365*5) and sum(case when work.CandidateId is null then 1 else 0 end) < (365/2) then DATEADD(year, 5, min(work.CalendarDate)) else null end as ViolationDate
from 
(
    select cand.CandidateId, cal.CalendarDate
    from CalendarTable cal
    join (select distinct c.CandidateId from contracts c where c.WorkPeriodStart is not null and c.WorkPeriodEnd is not null and c.Deleted = 0) cand on 1 = 1
    where cal.CalendarDate between @beginDate and @enddate
) as poss 
left join 
(
    select distinct c.CandidateId, cal.CalendarDate
    from contracts c
        join CalendarTable cal on cal.CalendarDate between c.WorkPeriodStart and c.WorkPeriodEnd 
    where c.WorkPeriodStart is not null and c.WorkPeriodEnd is not null and c.Deleted = 0
) as work on work.CandidateId = poss.CandidateId and work.CalendarDate = poss.CalendarDate
group by poss.CandidateId
```